# Why use subquery to get the original table?

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I came across a question from Leetcode.

https://leetcode.com/problems/delete-duplicate-emails/

One approach is below:

`DELETE FROM Person WHERE
Id NOT IN (SELECT MIN(p.Id) FROM (SELECT * FROM Person) p
Group by p.Email);`

I wonder why it needs a subquery for the table itself `(SELECT MIN(p.Id) FROM (SELECT * FROM Person)` instead of just `(SELECT MIN(p.Id) FROM Person p)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a hack in MySQL.  MySQL does not allow `DELETE` or `UPDATE` to directly reference the table being modified.  The extra subquery materializes the table and allows the code to work.

Many people would write this using `JOIN` instead:

```
DELETE p
    FROM Person p JOIN
         (SELECT p2.email, MIN(p2.ID) as min_id
          FROM person p2
          GROUP BY p2.email
         ) pp
         ON pp.email = p.email
    WHERE p.id > pp.id;
```